# Wrapping an aggregate inside an aggregate function in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

We are using a `CLR Aggregate function` `dbo.GetList(@value, @order, @sep)` in our scripts. This function works similarly to `STRING_AGG()` function. `@order` is the order in which we want aggregation. Now we want to wrap `STRING_AGG()` inside `dbo.GetList()` function. Basically an aggregate inside an aggregate. Is it possible? if yes, then how?

Below is the definition of dbo.GetList() function.

```
CREATE AGGREGATE dbo.GetList
(
  @Value nvarchar(max), 
  @order int,
  @sep nvarchar(400)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(max)
EXTERNAL NAME [Sql_Clr].[StringConcat]
GO
```

PS: We want wrapper only as we do not want to replace old function directly with `STRING_AGG()` in 100's of scripts & reinvent the issues.

Comment: You can't aggregate an aggregate no. an `AGGREGATE`, however, is expected to reference a .Net Assembly, so the above isn't even valid.

Comment: Nevermind, it's been edited to now be a `FUNCTION`. This, however, doesn't make sense. You aren't aggregating an aggregate (`STRING_AGG`?) here, and the values you *are* "aggregating" are scalar values. String `STRING_AGG` of a scalar value is the scalar value... It's like doing `SELECT SUM(10)` and expecting a value other than `10`.

Comment: Inside _what_ aggregate function? Do you mean a CLR function you've created, or do you mean putting `STRING_AGG()` inside, say, `MAX()`? Could you provide a little more context?

Comment: Yes @Larnu found that & have changed my code. The above one is getting created however I can't use it in the SELECT statment. Its simply cant find this function & prompts error column dbo not found.

Comment: How are you referencing the function, @Aditya ? If you've got SQL that's erroring include that SQL and the error in your question.

Comment: Sounds like you are just calling it wrong. A table-valued function is `SELECT * FROM dbo.function(...)`, a scalar function is `SELECT dbo.function(...)`. Again, please provide more context. You probably want `SELECT * FROM dbo.table AS t CROSS APPLY dbo.GetList(t.SomeColumn, ...)`

Comment: @AaronBertrand I want to create a wrapper for STRING_AGG() function which can be used in the SELECT statement itself like a table column.

Comment: So provide the details around that, don't just show us your function code and say how do I do some thing. Show the table you want to query against, and the output you expect. Your function might not even be the best way to do what you want to do, yet that's all you've shown us about your problem.

Comment: @AaronBertrand does it make sense now?

Comment: trying to avoid refactoring existing code now that `string_agg` is available.  I suggest however refactoring is exactly what you need to do. Even if you placed string_agg is a wrapper - you are still going to do the same amount of regression testing, but the advantage is now you code is using standard functionality.

Comment: *"Below is the definition of dbo.GetList() function."* but now we need the code within `[Sql_Clr].[StringConcat]`.

Comment: @Larnu "code within [Sql_Clr].[StringConcat]" No. Want to replace this with STRING_AGG() standard function.

Comment: Then you don't need a function, you would do that in the outer query. We, therefore, need to know what you're existing outer query is, and we can show you how to use `STRING_AGG`, though the documentation, [STRING_AGG (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15), does given multiple examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. You need to refactor the code and start using the new `STRING_AGG` function.

The good thing is you can do this on steps as your function currently works.

I am in your shoes - having various splitter and concatenation functions written in SQL CLR in order to improve the performance and mate, I am using them for years... but using built-in functions is for sure the right thing to do and now I am paying the price of rewriting legacy code.

And it's not bad. I hope to get built-in regular expression support, too and give up the SQL CLR stuff I have written as I believe Microsoft are better in implementing such functionalities.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in using a windowed form of the agregate function... Because you do not provide the complet SQL query, it is difficult to answer. But something like :

```
SELECT SUM(COUNT(...) OVER(...))
```

does work.